# Keep point when converting to float

Tags: javascript

I am sending numerical data to a server with an ajax call, like `0.77`, `100` and so on. When the server receives the data, it interprets `0.77` as a `double`, but `100` as an `int` as it lacks decimals. To get the number I use

```
var nbr = parseFloat(stringVariable, 10);
```

and even if I try to input `100.0` it will thus remove my decimals as `parseFloat` removes them.

Is there any way to keep my decimal places so that the server can distinguish from the data types?

Comment: Wouldn't the server already handle this when the data comes back?

Comment: Could you please try: `var nbr = parseFloat(stringVariable, 10).toFixed(2);`?

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart The toFixed(2) approach does not work as it then returns a string instead of a number, and when the server then parses the JSON it will be considered a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently no numeric types other than Number in Javascript. In order to preserve decimals like you're asking, you'd have to send them as a string.

Comment: Yeah ok, I kind of guessed, I'll have to solve it server side then instead. Cheers!